# Using bi-directional popen

Tags: pipe, c, macos

Bi-directional `popen()` functionality was added in FreeBSD 2.2.6 and is available in MacOS. I have a C program that writes a stream of newline-separated strings, and I'd like for it to pipe this to a Perl tool I wrote called **cols** that reads such a stream from STDIN, buffers it, and then writes it to STDOUT in a multicolumn, vertically-sorted format.

In the C program, I use:

`FILE *cols_pipe = popen("cols", "r+");` to open the pipe and start **cols**;

`fprintf( cols_pipe, "%s\n", word );` to send each newline-terminated word to cols; and

```
while ((getline(&line_buf, &line_buf_len, cols_pipe)) != -1) {
     printf("%s", line_buf);
}
```

to read back and print the reformatted lines from **cols**. When the program hung at `getline()` I realized it was because **cols** hadn't received EOF on STDIN, but closing **cols_pipe** (the only way I can think of to send EOF) would prevent me from reading back.

Obviously, **cols** can't begin to write its output until it's read all the input.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? The C program is interactive so I don't want to simply invoke it from the command line with STDOUT piped to **cols**.

Comment: Sounds more like a buffering issue. Maybe you need a `setvbuf()` on cols_pipe to disable buffering or make it line-based or call fflush() after your fprintf()

Comment: You'll likely also want to disable buffering in `perl` for the reverse direction (see `perldoc -v '$|'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added those but it still hangs, presumably because Perl program is still waiting to read EOF.

Comment: If the perl program does `@all_lines=<STDIN>` and the `print "something"` then yes, it waits for EOF and you can't use popen(r+). If it does `while(<STDIN>){print "something";}` reading one line at a time, then you should be able to interact with it with your cols_pipe, but you'll likely still have a problem in the end if you need to signify EOF to cols and still read more output from it after that. You'd probably be better of using two pipes or a socketpair where you can shutdown directions independently. I've never used FreeBSD's popen(r+) or bidirectional pipes, they don't seem very useful

Comment: Also note that if cols starts outputting something before it has finished reading its input, you may end up in a deadlock situation if the data to be processed doesn't fit whole in the pipe buffer if at the other end you don't start reading cols output until you've finished send data to it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I agree it doesn't appear very useful. I decided on a quick fix and added an optional parameter to `cols` declaring an EOF marker which the C program sends in lieu of actual eof. Same idea as Perl's heredoc. Better would be two pipes, as you suggest.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if you want to write your observations as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Perl program (as written) expects EOF on STDIN, and the only way to effect this is to close the input pipe, this won't work with `popen()`. Since you own the Perl code, however, you might consider adding a command option to defines a special token that indicates "end of input", much in the grand tradition of "heredocs", so that it can recognize the end of the input stream and begin to respond without the input pipe being closed.